# Gradle bootJar task skip encoding some file

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

Here is a keystore file in springboot resources directory, when I ran bootJar task I found this file got bigger. I found it was because of a change in a way it was encodes.

I knew maven can solve this issue by adding `nonFilteredFileExtension` config. But how to solve this problem in Gradle

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by setting **processResource** config.

First I set DupicatesStrategy to **EXCLUDE** to make sure the first founded file can be inclueded. After that I exclude and then include that file to achieve the purpose.

```
processResources {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    from('/src/main/resources') {
        exclude("*.keystore")
    }
    from('/src/main/resources') {
        include("*.keystore")
    }
}
```